# Conditionally show group headers in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

I am trying to write a report that in ssrs that looks like this:

```
Manager Name                      |  [ Employees for Manager ]  | Total Hours Spent
[ All projects team worked on ]   |  [ Hours Employee Spent ]   | [ Sum of Teams Hours ]
Total                             |  [ Total Employee Hours ]   | [ Total Team Hours ]
```

I have the query rolled up to show a row for every manager, employee and project and I have the correct groupings listed. But my problem is getting only the employees that belong to the current manager group to be shown and not show all employees.

So the result set looks like this:

Manager Name, Employee Name, Proj Name, Project Time

I have a manager row grouping and an employee column grouping but I can't figure out how to only show the employees that match the manager in the current group. I think I must be missing something but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

A columns will belong to the same group across every row group. In your case, the column group sounds like it is EmployeeName. So you can't have a column belong to one employee in one group, but another employee in a different group. SSRS doesn't work that way.

So to get what you are looking for, I would have a subreport or a "sub" matix repeating in the rows of your table. Use the table's Manager name as a parameter for the subreport (or a filter for the matrix.)

Comment: Yeah that could work. I hadn't thought about a sub report with manager name as param. I was hoping there was an easy way to hide and show columns based on that grouping but I'll give this a shot.